# JavaFX, SceneBuilder, Populating TableView with MySQL Result Set

Tags: mysql, javafx, tableview, scenebuilder

I have finally overcome my issue with a NPE in my code whilst learning FX/FXML. I now however have a different problem, a window opens with my TableView however there is no content in the table at all. As you cann I have printed out the JobList to make sure there is content being returned, and this returns three jobs (the correct amount). Am I missing something that binds the table to the returned list?

Here is the code;

```
public class SecondInterface implements Initializable {

    private JobDataAccessor jAccessor;
    private String aQuery = "SELECT * FROM progdb.adamJobs";
    private Parent layout;
    private Connection connection;
    @FXML
    TableView<Job> tView;

    public void newI(Connection connection) throws Exception {

        Stage primaryStage;
        primaryStage = MainApp.primaryStage;

        this.connection = connection;
        System.out.println(connection);

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Test1.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            layout = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

        primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(layout);
    }

    public Parent getLayout() {
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        jAccessor = new JobDataAccessor();

        try {
            System.out.println("This connection: " + connection);
            System.out.println("This query: " + aQuery);
            List<Job> jList = jAccessor.getJobList(connection, aQuery);
            for (Job j : jList) {
                System.out.println(j);
            }
            tView.getItems().addAll(jAccessor.getJobList(connection, aQuery));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you loading the FXML file twice?

Comment: Good question - I couldn't work out how to show a new scene by utilisting the FXMLoader (I.E nothing appears). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just do `new Scene(layout)` instead of `new Scene(p)`, and skip the second call to `load(...)`

Comment: Thanks @James_D, any advice on the no content in the TableView? Funnily enough I can select the three jobs that are added, they just have no text displayed in the columns.

Comment: I think the fact that you are displaying one view and manipulating a controller from another view is why you don't see any content. Fix the structure first (which I don't fully understand: are you using one controller for multiple FXML files?) and then see if it still doesn't work.

Comment: But also, why are you creating new `TableColumn`s in `initialize()` if they are already created in the FXML file?

Comment: I have two Java files and two FXML files, each Java file controls their FXML file, is this the correct setup? To be honest I had a working application that I'm now trying to port to SceneBuilder and FXML, I'm still trying to get the grasp of the "correct" setup of the files.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. Each FXML file should have its own controller class. Usually you let the fxml file just instantiate the controller via a  `fx:controller` attribute, but here I guess you are creating the controller class "by hand" and then calling `newI(...)` directly (which is a perfectly good approach, especially if you need to pass data (e.g. your `Connection`) to the controller). You should fix it so you are not reinitializing the table columns, and so you are only calling `load()` once, and update the question if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @James_D, I have removed the column initialisation, however I am not 100% sure I understand what you mean by only calling load() once. I'm still having the same issue, I believe the jobs are added as I can select them however there is no text in any of the columns.

Comment: Ah, ok, you updated the code.

Comment: So now I guess you need to show the FXML, particularly the `cellValueFactory` settings on the columns.

Comment: That is most likely my issue then, I don't seem to have done that! Is there a way to do this in Java? I'm probably more comfortable writing in Java than FXML.

Comment: Yes, just set the [`cellValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty) directly on each of the `TableColumn`s in the `initialize()` method

Comment: @James_D, thanks for all your help, I now have the jobs displayed in the table. Only issue I have left is that the last column now has no data in. I assume something is mismatched along the way. Should the String prpoerty in `PropertyValueFactory` be matching something else? For example: `completedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Job, String>("completedSetting"));` is the column that is not displaying data. Should the completedSetting match up with something? EDIT: It didn't follow the setting in the Job model class. All updated now and works fine.